# Hide forms in MVC view page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 forms in MVC3 view page, based on certain conditon i have to hide one form, but i am receiving some error, could not find out what is the error?Below is the code,

```
@model Models.Common.Details
@{
    if (ViewContext.IsChildAction != true && !Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    { Layout = "../../Shared/DefaultLayout.cshtml"; }
    else
    { Layout = null; }
}

@using Models.Common;
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Premium";}
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var urlContent = "@Url.Content("~/")";
    var currentYear = "@DateTime.Now.Year";
    var currentMonth = "@DateTime.Now.Month";
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/UIScripts/paymentmodule/Premium.js?" + DateTime.Now)" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber1)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber2)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber3)
<input type="submit"  id="Settle" name="Settle"  value="Settle"/>
}

@{
if (!(Session["User"].Equals(Constant.User))) 
{
@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.post,new{@action="www.somelink.com/abce"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber4)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber5)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber6)
<input type="submit"  id="ok" name="Ok"  value="Settle"/>
}
}
}
```

I have used this code @{-----} to write c# conditon based on that condition i need to hide the 2nd form, since it is view page, i am not sure what error is coming, but i am not able to go to this view page itself. 
If i remove that block of code @{-----}, everything works fine.
Any suggestion guys?

```
Error Message:
UserMessage=  Error Occurred at  : 07/08/2014 12:03:02.547 
 Exception Details : System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Unexpected "using" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "using" with "@".
```

Comment: see the answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax for if condition is below.

```
@if (!(Session["User"].Equals(Constant.User)))
{
    using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.post, new { @action = "www.somelink.com/abce" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber4)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber5)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber6)
        <input type="submit" id="ok" name="Ok" value="Settle" />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remvoe the `@` sign which is before using begin form .. and correct `FormMethod.post` to `FormMethod.Post` with capital **P**.

When you are already inside c# code you don't need to use @ before the using.

Comment: Removing @ before using is working fine. But in other condition i need to use the 2nd form as well, so that time i need to use @ right? thatswhy i need to use at before using..                      I have already used capital P only, in questin mispelled the word. Thanks anyway

Comment: Your problems are comming because you put your code in razor code block - @{ ... }. You don't need this construction. When you need if or using just start typing @if(condition) { .. } or @using(Html.Form .. ) { ... } wihout wrapping it in code block :) .. It depends on situation when you need to use @. If you are already in C# code you don't need it. It's little tricky in the begining but it become natural with time :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your if like this and it is `FormMethod.Post` not `FormMethod.post` :

```
@if (!(Session["User"].Equals(Constant.User))) 
{
using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post,new{@action="www.somelink.com/abce"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber4)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber5)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber6)
<input type="submit"  id="ok" name="Ok"  value="Settle"/>
}
}
```

As by using **@** you are telling the compiler that c# code started so inside **if block** you don't need to put again **@** before **BeginFom**

Comment: Removing @ before using is working fine. But in other condition i need to use the 2nd form as well, so that time i need to use @ right? thatwhy i need to use at before using..

Comment: i think it will also work.. i may be wrong.. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

write second if like

```
@if (!(Session["User"].Equals(Constant.User))) 
{
   //remove @ here and make p of post capital like Post
    using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post,new{@action="www.somelink.com/abce"}))
  {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber4)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber5)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber6)
    <input type="submit"  id="ok" name="Ok"  value="Settle"/>
  }
}
```

Although for better readability and maintenance i would suggest you to use partial pages like

```
@if (SomeCondition)
{ 
  @Html.Partial("_firstPage")
}
else if (OtherCondition)
{
  @Html.Partial("_secondPage")
}
```